# wooCommerce js links suddenly broken

Tags: php, jquery, woocommerce

Suddenly and quite unexpectedly ...
The Add to cart button dosen't show up after selecting a product variation!

Upon opening the console and refreshing the page I could see that the following script could not be found :

http://rubengalarreta.com/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/assets/js/jquery-cookie/jquery.cookie.min.js?ver=1.3.1

which seems to be causing the error..

when i went into the index page of the product from the console.

I saw that the script source links are broken!! .. the "http:" part is missing from it and from some other scripts too!

Please can some one tell me how can I fix this??

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The missing http: isn't the problem. That's just a protocol-relative url which browsers interpret to mean "use the same protocol as the current page". This is typically used to make code work with both http and https sites.

It looks like you're running into some kind of apache config problem. [Apache is saying that this file is there](http://rubengalarreta.com/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/assets/js/jquery-cookie/) but when you try to access it, you get a 404.

See if this is the issue: http://docs.woothemes.com/document/jquery-cookie-fails-to-load/

Comment: You have saved me from a lot of heartache! :D